# Why won't this loop variable increment?

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to write code that will count the number of users returned by a sqlite query and then split a 'bill' between those users, but for some reason my counter won't increment and I am getting a division by zero error. My code is here:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'database.php';
$db = new Database();
$name = $_POST['name'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$due = $_POST['due'];
$gid = $_GET['gid'];
$uid = $_SESSION['id'];
$count = 0;

$users = $db->query("select * from members where(gid='$gid');");
while($data = $users->fetchArray()) {
$count++;
}

$amount = $amount / $count;
while($data = $users->fetchArray()) {
if($data['uid'] == $uid) {
    continue;
} else {
    $temp = $data['uid'];
    $db->exec("insert into bills values(NULL,'$gid','$uid','$temp','$amount','$due','false','$name');");
}
}

header('Location:grouppage.php?gid='.$gid.'');
?>
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Obvious question--are there any results returned by the query?

Comment: And either way, you need to put some logic in place to handle that eventuality

Comment: Yes there are, there should be 4, I just ran the query through sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the loop not seeming to work, you can't have two `while(... fetchArray())` loops without something resetting the internal pointer.

In this case, however, you don't need that:

```
$users = $db->query("select * from members where(gid='$gid')");
$count = $users->numRows();
if( $count == 0) die("No users found!");
$amount /= $count;
while($data = $users->fetchArray()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Apparently, numRows() is an undefined method :S

Comment: [The docs say otherwise](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-num-rows.php). Areyou sure you are using the sqlite library?

Comment: Guys I fixed it. I feel so stupid.... I'd messed up one of my urls so that the gid wasnt being passed properly :( Thankyou for all the help though, really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You don't handle case, when select doesn't return any record.

Just look at your code:

```
$users = $db->query("select * from members where(gid='$gid');");
while($data = $users->fetchArray()) {
$count++;
}
```

No data selected -- no while-body
executed, $count not incremented and left zero, with "divide by zero" error in following line as consequence.

```
$amount = $amount / $count;
```